# How does toilet training a puppy regress?

Tags: dogs, training, toilet-training

We have a 4 month old puppy who has done very well in her toilet training. She know's to go outside for a pee and a poo now and we barely have any accidents anywhere else in the house.

We have training pads by the back door for when we are not in the house, or when we don't get to her in time. She uses these no problem for peeing, and uses another area very close to the door for pooping!

The thing I worry about now is when we are at work and she is using the puppy pads, will this cause regression in her training? Will she learn to hold it on her own until she can go outside? Or do I need to do something else to help with this?

Comment: I assume you have to find a way to make her feel more comfortable at the outside than on the mat. If she likes more to go to the outside she will wait for it long as she could. Only then she goes to the puppy mat. The outside should be more attracting than the mat. Maybe someone with more experience could work out how to reach this :)

Comment: It sounds like you’re doing everything right, the older they get the longer they can hold it for so there’s a chance they may even stop using the pads until they can go outside

Comment: I can confirm, she's now just over a year and is much better at holding it!